# Database entry of Select tag selection by user goes as NULL. How do I put selection ID up there in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I put selection ID up there in database?

I am bit new to ruby on rails. I am trying to setup a form which has birthplace combobox which is populated from birthplaces database.

**Database: birthplaces**

```
Id  birthplace  created_at  updated_at
1   New York    -------------   -------------
2   London      -------------   -------------
```

Form submission should go to employees’ database with id of selection made by user at combobox.
For example user put Nick with birthplace combobox selection New York then it should go like this

**Database: employees**

```
Id  name        birthplace  created_at  updated_at
1   Nick        1       -------------   -------------
```

**Code: new.html.erb**
`

```
<%= form_for(@employees) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :birthplace %>
<%= select("post", :birthplace, @birthplace.collect {|p| [ p.birthplace, p.id ]}, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} )%>
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

'

**Code: employees_controller.rb**

```
Def new
@employees =Employee.new
    @birthplace = Birthplace.all
  end

  def create
    @birthplace = Birthplace.all
@employees = Employee.new (params[:employees])
    if @student.save

 flash[:success]= "Welcome to AVIS!"
        render 'new'
    else
        flash[:success]= "Some Errors!"
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: its not student.save but employees.save

Comment: have u tried by changing `@student.save`  To  `@employees.save`

Comment: Yes, actually I have mistyped while posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating an association between `Employee` and `Birthplace`.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :birthplace
end
```

And your form:

```
<%= form_for(@employees) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :birthplace %>
<%= f.select(:birthplace, Birthplace.all.collect{|p| [ p.birthplace, p.id ]}, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'}) %>
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Now you can use the information from the form directly in your controller.

```
def new
  @employee = Employee.new
end

def create
  @employee = Employee.new params[:employee]
  if @employee.save
    flash[:success]= "Welcome to AVIS!"
    render 'new'
  else
    flash[:error]= "Some Errors!"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Using Strong Parameters https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

```
def new
  @employee = Employee.new
end

def create
  @employee = Employee.new employee_params
  if @employee.save
    flash[:success]= "Welcome to AVIS!"
    render 'new'
  else
    flash[:error]= "Some Errors!"
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :birthplace_id)
end
```

Comment: You could make it work without the association by having your param like `param[:employee][:birthplace_id]`.

Comment: Thanks. But could you please provide more light on the same with strong parameters, I am kinda stuck there. Without strong params it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I added the strong parameters case. It should work with `:birthplace_id`, but if don't let me know how the HTML is being generated so I can have a better insight.